# SED pars two values from output file

Tags: sed

I am having hard time try figure out how to pars two values from below output:

```
   CHANNEL(SYSTEM.DEF.SVRCONN)             CHLTYPE(SVRCONN)
   ALTDATE(2022-11-06)                     ALTTIME(21.48.22)
   CERTLABL( )                             COMPHDR(NONE)
   COMPMSG(NONE)                           DESCR( )
   DISCINT(0)                              HBINT(300)
   KAINT(AUTO)                             MAXINST(999999999)
   MAXINSTC(999999999)                     MAXMSGL(4194304)
   MCAUSER( )                              MONCHL(QMGR)
   RCVDATA( )                              RCVEXIT( )
   SCYDATA( )                              SCYEXIT( )
   SENDDATA( )                             SENDEXIT( )
   SHARECNV(10)                            SSLCAUTH(REQUIRED)
   SSLCIPH( )                              SSLPEER( )
   TRPTYPE(TCP)
```

I have tired this, but does not work.

```
echo 'dis CHANNEL(SYSTEM.DEF.SVRCONN)' | runmqsc QREP311 | sed -n 's/.*\(CHLTYPE.*\).*\(MCAUSER.*\)/\1 \2/p'
```

Desire or expecting output like this:

CHLTYPE(SVRCONN)  MCAUSER( )

Comment: [There](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) you will find information on how to format your question with Markdown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using gnu awk you could use:

```bash
$ awk '{if (match($0,/CHLTYPE([^)]+))|MCAUSER([^)]+))/,m)) f? f=f" "m[0]: f=m[0]} END{print f}' file
CHLTYPE(SVRCONN) MCAUSER( )
```

If either of the two patterns of interest are found (so `CHLTYPE` and `MCAUSER` with whatever in brackets) then build an output string with the match.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -nE '/CHLTYPE/{:a;N;/MCAUSER/!ba
           s/.*(CHLTYPE\([^)]*\)).*(MCAUSER\([^)]*\)).*/\1 \2/p}' file
```

Match on `CHLTYPE` and the gather up the following lines until a match of `MCAUSER`.

Then using pattern matching extract and print the required values.

N.B. The `-nE` options which suppress printing and enable simpler regexps.